# Mudanças vocálicas na primeira pessoa singular

Tags: gramática, verbos, conjugações

Alguns verbos *-ir* na primeira pessoa no presente de indicativo mudam a vogal na sua raiz. Normalmente, coincidem com os verbos que realizam uma chamada «alternáncia vocálica» noutras línguas ibéricas como mirandês, asturiano, ou castelhano, mas não parece haver uma correspondência perfeita e por tanto é difícil me lembrar os verbos que precisam a mudança e claro, tem consequências importantes para a flexão no presente de conjuntivo e no imperativo. Mas não posso encontrar nenhuma lista de estes verbos. Então

1. Qual é o nome que se da a esta mudança em português?
2. É possível predizê-la ou há uma lista dos verbos que a sofrem?

Comment: Alguém poderia dar ao menos um exemplo para eu entender do que se trata?

Comment: @Math Por exemplo, o **e** de *mentir* vira **i** em *eu minto*.

Comment: Não seria "presente do indicativo"?

Answer (score 2):

A mudança parece chamar-se *alternância vocálica* mesmo. E há [aqui](http://educacao.uol.com.br/disciplinas/portugues/conjugacao-dos-verbos-irregulares---3-conjugacao-verbos-com-alternancia-vocalica.htm) uma lista enorme desses verbos com instruções para a sua conjugação.